# Filter groups of data that contain consecutive values from list

Tags: r

Example data:

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C')
Hour <- c('0','2','5','6','9','0','2','5','6','0','5','6','9')
Intensity <- as.numeric(c('220','192','180','175','140','227','193','163','144','232','205','190','185'))

x <- data.frame(ID, Hour, Intensity)

x
   ID Hour Intensity
1   A    0       220
2   A    2       192
3   A    5       180
4   A    6       175
5   A    9       140
6   B    0       227
7   B    2       193
8   B    5       163
9   B    6       144
10  C    0       232
11  C    5       205
12  C    6       190
13  C    9       185
```

I want to remove all rows associated with an `ID` where there are non-consecutive values of `Hour`, according to this list:

```
uniqueHoursOrder <- sort(unique(Hour))

uniqueHoursOrder
[1] "0" "2" "5" "6" "9"
```

I want to include any `ID` so long as it has a row for the first value of `uniqueHoursOrder` (i.e. 0) and it's other rows follow in order according to the order of `uniqueHoursOrder`. It's OK if an `ID` doesn't have a row for every value of `Hour` in `uniqueHoursOrder`.

For this data, the result should be:

```
   ID Hour Intensity
1   A    0       220
2   A    2       192
3   A    5       180
4   A    6       175
5   A    9       140
6   B    0       227
7   B    2       193
8   B    5       163
9   B    6       144
```

(`ID` C is excluded because it's missing `Hour` 2. B is included because it has consecutive values of `Hour` starting with 0, even though it doesn't have rows for `Hour` for all values in `uniqueHoursOrder`.)

A dplyr solution would be ideal, but I'll take any help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'ID', `match` the 'Hour' with 'uniqueHoursOrder', get the `diff` of the index, check whether `all` the difference is equal to 1 and use that logical index to subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .SD[all(diff(match(Hour, uniqueHoursOrder))==1)], ID]
#    ID Hour Intensity
#1:  A    0       220
#2:  A    2       192
#3:  A    5       180
#4:  A    6       175
#5:  A    9       140
#6:  B    0       227
#7:  B    2       193
#8:  B    5       163
#9:  B    6       144
```

---

The same methodology can be used with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(diff(match(Hour, uniqueHoursOrder))==1))
```

Comment: Would this work if there is an `ID` with `Hour`: 0, 2, 5 though?

Comment: @useR  The OP gave an input dataset and I tested it on that.  I didn't say anything about the other cases nor did the OP

Comment: Your solution is specific to the example OP gave though, but not general enough to incorporate the rules lined out by OP. Specifically, "I want to include any ID so long as it has a row for the first value of uniqueHoursOrder (i.e. 0) and it's other rows follow in order according to the order of uniqueHoursOrder. It's OK if an ID doesn't have a row for every value of Hour in uniqueHoursOrder."

Comment: This seems to be working, although I don't totally understand how. How does this check for consecutive values?

Comment: @useR I tried your  example `x1 <- x[-9];
 x1[, .SD[all(diff(match(Hour, uniqueHoursOrder))==1)], ID]` and it give the 'ID' A and B

Comment: @holastello  It is based on the `match` to find the index of the element in the column.  If the index element is not in the order, then the difference will not 1 and that is the reason 'C' is not included